# Insert HTML programmatically in wysiHTML5 editor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I found javascript wysiwyg editor [wysiHTML5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5).

I'm trying to add element `<a href=...>` to the editor or just turn on bold programmatically.

My code is:

```
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("textarea", {
    toolbar:      "toolbar",
    stylesheets:  "css/wysihtml5.css",
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
});

editor.observe("load", function() {
    editor.composer.commands.exec("bold");
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually no, but you have to be sure that your textarea (iframe) is focused. Try to use `on` instead of `observe`. Here is a sample code that worked for me with insertHTML.

```
editor.on("load", function() {
  editor.focus();
  editor.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML","<a href=....>text</a>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out, it should really be in the docs

Comment: If you don't mind erasing the html in the editor you can use the setValue command i.e editor.setValue("<a href=...>");

Comment: Please note your colon at the end of the script. Should it be a semicolon?

Comment: Added semicolon, I was in too hurry to read comment and spent half hour to notice that

Comment: This worked very well for me. But how do I blur/unfocus the editor after the "insertHTML" insertion? I have tried a few things, amongst other `editor.blur()` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

mateusmaso's solution gave me the following error:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.execCommand]
[Break On This Error]   

Object.defineProperty(object, property, config);
```

So I've investigated some more and found the following solution, which (IMO) seems more ok:

```
var value = 'whatever you want to set';
// The jQuery reference to the textarea
var $ta = $('textarea#your-selector');
// The reference to the wysihtml5 editor - everything is contained within it 
var w5ref = $ta.data('wysihtml5');
// Check if you have it
if(w5ref){
   // if yes it's really an enhanced / wysihtml5ed textarea 
   // and use its setter
   w5ref.editor.setValue(value);
} else {
   // otherwise just simply populate the textarea as you normally would
   $ta.html(value);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/issues/67)

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have instantiated the editor previously using `$('#textarea-id').wysihtml5()`

```
$('#textarea-id').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue('new content');
```

[font](https://www.codementor.io/tips/0643978211/update-wysihtml5-editor-content-dynamically-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution