# jQuery: changing iframe content

Tags: jquery, iframe, wysihtml5

As far as I can tell this code should work, but it doesn't and I'm totally stumped. Any thoughts?

**jQuery**

```
$('.article_chooser').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('value');
$("#doc_edits_attributes_0_body").parent("iframe html body").html($("#article"+src).html());
console.log($("#doc_edits_attributes_0_body").parent("iframe html body").html());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="editable_areas" cols="40" id="doc_edits_attributes_0_body" name="doc[edits_attributes][0][body]" rows="20" style="display: none;"></textarea>
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <html>
        <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" class="editable_areas wysihtml5-editor" spellcheck="true">
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Cheers!

Comment: You do of course realize that setting the security attribute to restricted, will disable all scripting in the iFrame for browsers that supports that attribute, and any attempt to use javascript on the iFrame will generally fail ?

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't realise. The iframe is created with a plugin. I guess I need to adjust it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wysihtml5` plugin has API, you can use `getValue` method:

```
var value = editorInstance.getValue();
```

Or if you want to set a value, you can use `setValue` method:

```
editorInstance.setValue('a string');
```

Or if you want to append html content you can use `.exec()` method:

```
editorInstance.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", "<p>bar</p>");
```

Comment: So presumably `setValue();` would do the opposite, yeah? Are there docs available for the API? I can't find any.

Comment: @emm Yes, it does, actually I used `console.dir` for seeing what properties and methods it provides/supports, you can examine it's github wiki page https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/

Comment: This will work, I imagine, once I learn how to refer to each instance of the editor. Is it the ID of the textarea it's replacing? So in my example above it'd be `$("#doc_edits_attributes_0_body")`? The iframe code reveals no identifier.

Comment: @emm Well, you can store the returned object in a variable when you are initialising the plugin, then you can call the methods on that instance.

Comment: I'm about to show my ignorance here and confess that I've no idea what that means. Ha.

Comment: @emm Oh, sorry, I meant this: `var editor = new wysihtml5(...)`.

Comment: Ah, right! I've got `var cmon = $('.editable_areas').wysihtml5();` and `cmon.setValue($("#article"+src).html());`, but I get `Object has no method 'setValue'`.

Comment: Your answer coupled with [matyas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739237/insert-html-programatically-in-wysihtml5-editor)' answer here works!

Answer (score 8):

To edit the content of an iframe you must call the `body` tag inside the iframe:

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="iframe">
    <html>
        <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" class="editable_areas wysihtml5-editor" spellcheck="true">
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframe').contents().find('body').html('New Content');
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the contents method to get the document element of an iframe http://api.jquery.com/contents/ hopefully I would not forget this niche function.

Comment: In my case that should translate to this: `$("#doc_edits_attributes_0_body").parent("iframe").contents().find('body').html($("#article"+src).html());`? I still get nothing.